# C++ polymorphism: how to create derived class objects

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have an abstract base class called `BaseStrategy`. It contains one pure virtual function `calculateEfficiency()`. There are two classes `ConvolutionStrategy` and `MaxPoolStrategy` which derive from this base class and implement their own specific version of `calculateEfficiency()`.

Here is some code:

```
class BaseStrategy {
public:
    explicit BaseStrategy();
    virtual ~BaseStrategy() = default;

private:
    virtual double calculateEfficiency(mlir::Operation* op) = 0;
};

class ConvolutionStrategy : public BaseStrategy {
private:
    double calculateEfficiency(mlir::Operation* op)
    {
        //some formula for convolution 
        return 1;
    }
};

class MaxPoolStrategy : public BaseStrategy {
private:
    double calculateEfficiency(mlir::Operation* op)
    {
        //some formula for MaxPool
        return 1;
    }
};
```

Now I have another class called `StrategyAssigner`. It has method `calculateAllLayerEfficiencies()` whose purpose is to iterate over all layers in a network. Depending on the type of layer there is a switch statement and should call the correct `calculateEfficiency()` depending on the layer type.

```
class StrategyAssigner final {
public:
    explicit StrategyAssigner(){};

public:
    void calculateAllLayerEfficiencies() {
        // Logic to iterate over all layers in
        // a network
        switch (layerType) {
        case Convolution:
            // Call calculateEfficiency() for Convolution
            break;
        case MaxPool:
            // Call calculateEfficiency() for MaxPool
            break;
        }
    };
}

int main ()
{
    StrategyAssigner assigner;
    assigner.calculateAllLayerEfficiencies();
}
```

My question is, should I store references of objects Convolution and MaxPool in the class `StrategyAssigner` so that I can call the respective `calculateEfficiency()`.

Or could you suggest a better way to call `calculateEfficiency()`. I don't really know how to create the objects (stupid as that sounds).

I can't make `calculateEfficiency()` static as I need them to be virtual so that each derived class can implemented its own formula.

Comment: If you need to use a `switch` anyway, you probably don't need polymorphism.

Comment: `ConvolutionStrategy cs;` - that's how you instantiate the object of your convolution strategy. Then you can call `cs.calculateEfficiency();`. In this example it doesn't matter if ConvolutionStrategy is polymorphic or no. It would make more sense in case you got `BaseStrategy* strategy;` somewhere and instantiate it with `ConvolutionStrategy*` or `MaxPoolStrategy*`, depending on your logic.

Comment: If you store the objects as `BaseStrategy` you can then just call from that and it will call the implemented method on whatever class it is.  If you care what subclass the object is then a dynamic cast will work if it is the type you want, or retur NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed use runtime polymorphism here:

- Declare `~BaseStrategy` virtual (you are already doing it ;-)
- If you are never going to instantiate a `BaseStrategy`, declare one of its methods as virtual pure, e.g. `calculateEfficiency` (you are already doing it as well!). I would make that method `const`, since it doesn't look it's going to modify the instance. And it will need to be public, because it will need to be accessed from `StrategyAnalyser`.
- Declare `calculateEfficiency` as `virtual` and `override` in each of the subclasses. It could also be `final` if you don't want subclasses to override it.
- I'd keep a `std::vector` of smart pointers to `BaseStrategy` at `StrategyAssigner`. You can use `unique_ptr`s if you think this class is not going to be sharing those pointers.
- The key point now is that you create heap instances of the subclasses and assign them to a pointer of the base class.

```cpp
class StrategyAssigner final {
public:
    void addStrategy(std::unique_ptr<BaseStrategy> s) {
        strategies_.push_back(std::move(s));
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseStrategy>> strategies_{};
};

int main()
{
    StrategyAssigner assigner;
    assigner.addStrategy(std::make_unique<ConvolutionStrategy>());
}
```

- Then, when you call `calculateEfficiency` using any of those pointers to `BaseStrategy`, the runtime polymorphism will kick in and it will be the method for the subclass the one that will be actually called.

```cpp
class ConvolutionStrategy : public BaseStrategy {
private:
    virtual double calculateEfficiency() const override {
        std::cout << "ConvolutionStrategy::calculateEfficiency()\n";
        return 10;
    }
};

class MaxPoolStrategy : public BaseStrategy {
private:
    virtual double calculateEfficiency() const override {
        std::cout << "MaxPoolStrategy::calculateEfficiency()\n";
        return 20;
    }
};

class StrategyAssigner final {
public:
    void calculateAllLayerEfficiencies() {        
        auto sum = std::accumulate(std::cbegin(strategies_), std::cend(strategies_), 0,
            [](auto total, const auto& strategy_up) {
                return total + strategy_up->calculateEfficiency(); });
        std::cout << "Sum of all efficiencies: " << sum << "\n";
    };
};

int main()
{
    StrategyAssigner assigner;
    assigner.addStrategy(std::make_unique<ConvolutionStrategy>());
    assigner.addStrategy(std::make_unique<MaxPoolStrategy>());
    assigner.calculateAllLayerEfficiencies(); 
}

// Outputs:
//
//   ConvolutionStrategy::calculateEfficiency()
//   MaxPoolStrategy::calculateEfficiency()
//   Sum of all efficiencies: 30
```

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/e6b6Mxrnj)

Comment: many thanks for taking the time to respond with such a helpful answer.

Comment: My pleasure! I'm also learning :)

Answer (score 1):

If you included complete code I could give a more detailed answer, but you need to store BaseStrategy pointers that are initialized with derived class instances. Here's an example made from some of your code:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseStrategy>> strategies;
strategies.emplace_back(new ConvolutionStrategy);
strategies.emplace_back(new MaxPoolStrategy);

for (int i = 0; i < strategies.size(); ++i) {
    std::unique_ptr<BaseStrategy>& pStrat = strategies[i];
    pStrat->calculateEfficiency(...);
}
```

Note that this won't compile because I don't have enough details from the code you posted to make it so, but this shows how to exploit polymorphism in the way that you need.

Also, I used smart pointers for memory management; use these at your discretion.

Comment: Deserves an upvote for the smart pointers alone.